# jQuery on/off function with one button not working?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make my button work as a lights on and off, I tried this with two seperate buttons and it worked, but as I made it into one single button it doesn't work, it gives out the alerts, but doesn't change the styles, any suggestions? I kinda mixed javascript with jquery, maybe theres some syntax problems (i followed multiple tutorials on js and jquery)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#lights").click(function() {
    if (ijungtas == 0) {
      ijungtas = 1;
      alert("a")
    } else {
      ijungtas = 0
      alert("b")
    }
  });

  if (ijungtas == 1) {
    $("#lights").click(function() {
      $(".tamsus").css({
        display: 'block',
        "background-color": "black",
        "position": "absolute",
        "color": "#fff",
        "height": "100vh",
        "width": "100%",
        "z-index": "88",
      });
    });

    $("#lights").click(function() {
      $(".wrapper").css({
        display: 'none'
      });
    });

    $("#lights").click(function() {
      $(".right_side").css({
        "z-index": "999"
      });
    });
    $("#lights").click(function() {
      $("#test").css({
        "display": "none"
      });
    });
    $("#lights").click(function() {
      $(".room_box").css({
        "opacity": "0"
      });
    });

    $("#lights").click(function() {
      $("#hostname").css({
        "opacity": "0"
      });
    });
  }

  if (ijungtas == 0) {
    $("#lights").click(function() {
      $(".wrapper").css({
        display: 'block'
      });
    });

    $("#lights").click(function() {
      $(".right_side").css({
        "z-index": "0"
      });
    });

    $("#lights").click(function() {
      $(".tamsus").css({
        "display": "none"
      })
    });

    $("#lights").click(function() {
      $(".right_side").removeClass("active")
    });

    $("#lights").click(function() {
      $(".test").css({
        display: 'flex'
      });
    });

    $("#lights").click(function() {
      $("#test").css({
        "display": "inherit"
      });
    });

    $("#lights").click(function() {
      $(".room_box").css({
        "opacity": "1"
      });
    });

    $("#lights").click(function() {
      $("#hostname").css({
        "opacity": "1"
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.tamsus .active {
  display: none !important;
  background: black !important;
}

.left_container {
  z-index: 89 !important;
}

.room_box .active {
  font-size: 100px;
}

.chat .active {
  display: none !important;
  z-index: 99;
}

.test .active {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="focus-time" id="lights" value="Lights on/off">Lights on/off</button>
```

Comment: I added jQuery in your snippet and it creates syntax error, try running it. Use `console.log()` or debugger to troubleshoot instead of `alert`

Comment: "Cut and paste programming" will only get you so far. Ultimately there is no replacement for actually _understanding_ what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

You could really refactor this thing to be alot easier to read and maintain. Here is a suggestion:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ijungtas = false // lights off is the default
  
  $("#lights").click(function() {
    if (!ijungtas) {
      $("body").addClass('lights-on');
    } 
    else {
      $("body").removeClass('lights-on');
    }
    
    ijungtas = !ijungtas; //switch
  });
});
```

```css
body.lights-on {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="focus-time" id="lights" value="Lights on/off">Lights on/off</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This example can't work since all classes that you change are not in the html.

You can achieve the desired efect with only one event handler by toggling a class for the body and declaring the light-styles to your css like `body.enlighted .left_container {...}`. Because of the missing html elements i made my example just width the body.

**Working example**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#lights").click(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('enlighted');
    console.log('toggled');
  });
});
```

```css
.enlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="focus-time" id="lights" value="Lights on/off">Lights on/off</button>
```